# Enable Git in DreamWeaver 2021 on macOS

Tags: git, macos, dreamweaver

I'm try to enable Git in DW2021 on macOS.

My way:

1. Install Xcode(that comes with Git);
2. Install DreamWeaver 2021;
3. Also install GitHub Desktop(just because I can't work in DW)

When I try to add Git Repository to my project DW says:
[image: DWERROR]

In my Preferences:
[image: DWPREFERENCES]

I'm trying to provide couple warrants of preferences that I found on the internet, like:

1. usr/local/bin/git
2. usr/bin/git

In macOS terminal:

```
whereis git     
/usr/bin/git
```

and

```
git --version        
git version 2.30.1 (Apple Git-130)
```

Also I trying couple variants for terminal, but I think all of them was wrong.

Can somebody provide me right setting for app that cost $20/month, because free VS Code working fine without any additional settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after one more hour, finally, I found solution that seems to be working.
So, for macOS Big Sur, Xcode 12+ and DreamWeaver 2021 working Git solution is:

1. Install Xcode;
2. Install Xcode Command Line Tools(`xcode-select --install` in terminal)
3. Put those setting in DW Git Preferences:

Path to git you can find in terminal: `whereis git`

Path to Git Executable: **/usr/bin/git**

Path to Terminal: *Leave Blank*

Restart DreamWeaver and try to access Git terminal in Git window - must be working. Allow all requirements.

After configuring git user add `.DS_Store` to globally ignored files:

```
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore
echo .DS_Store >> ~/.gitignore
```